# .htaccess rewrite rule for username and index along with other pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am developing one website of resume upload, user can register and submit there resume, later they ll see there resume by entering a custom link like yourdomain.com/profile/username, 
now its all done but the thing is i rewrite an htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile_view.php?user_custom=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

now I have the problem is the client wants the URL like yourdomain.com/username

but when I rewrite the `.htaccess` to

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile_view.php?user_custom=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

by removing the `"profile/ "` then when ever am passing the username like yourdomain.com/username

there is no problem but am facing the problem when i open `yourdomain.com/index.php` the index page lost along with all other pages.

Can any one suggest a solution?

Comment: can you please put your htaccess code regarding index.php rule

Comment: you mean like this :- RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?user_custom=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: put your rule in profile directory then it will not effect other directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude file and directories from your rule by adding `RewriteCond` just before your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile_view.php?user_custom=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your gesture, it's really helped me out a really tensed situation,  Again Thanks a ton... :)

Comment: you're welcome, please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem. :)